# Splunk extract nested fields from JSON string

Tags: splunk

I have the below JSON string, and I need to extract amount.dollarAmt.
This is the query I tried but it's not working. What can I try next?

```
|rex "dollarAmt\"\:\"(?< dollarAmt >([^\"]+))" | spath output=dollarAmt path=amount. dollarAmt
```

```
  "myId": "6836c64a-37b3-4991-96c7-c558e3d7d94c",
  "storeId": "0",
  "deptId": "9",
  "eventPayload": {
    "orderNumber": "13456",
    "paymentMethod": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "dollarAmt": 27.29,
          "currencyUnit": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "actualAmt": {
          "dollarAmt": 7.29,
          "currencyUnit": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `spath` command only works with valid JSON, which is not the case with the example data.  Adding a leading `{` makes it work as in this run-anywhere example.  If you use `spath` without arguments then you'll see how Splunk names the fields.  Then you can specify the name in the `path=` argument.

```
| makeresults | eval _raw="{\"myId\": \"6836c64a-37b3-4991-96c7-c558e3d7d94c\",
  \"storeId\": \"0\",
  \"deptId\": \"9\",
  \"eventPayload\": {
    \"orderNumber\": \"13456\",
    \"paymentMethod\": [
      {
        \"amount\": {
          \"dollarAmt\": 27.29,
          \"currencyUnit\": \"USD\"
        }
      },
      {
        \"actualAmt\": {
          \"dollarAmt\": 7.29,
          \"currencyUnit\": \"USD\"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}" 
| spath output=dollarAmt path=eventPayload.paymentMethod{}.amount.dollarAmt
```